# Python ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. sample tutorial not working

Tags: python

I am following a tutorial to learn to read and write to a file.
I am getting the following error.  I do not understand why.

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Automation/Python/Write to files/test3.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Automation/Python/Write to files/test3.py", line 8, in <module>
    f.read('newfile.txt', 'r')
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

My code is

```
f = open("newfile.txt", "w")
f.write("hello world\n")
f.write("Another line\n")
f.close()

f.read('newfile.txt', 'r')
print f.read()
```

I have tried to put `f.close` at the bottom of the code but I still get the same error.

The write part works if I comment out the `f.read`.  It is failing on the `f.read` part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line after `f.close()` that is `f.read('newfile.txt', 'r')` should be `f = open('newfile.txt', 'r')`.

That is

```
f = open('newfile.txt', 'r')
print f.read()
f.close()
```

After which you need to add `f.close()` again.

**Small Note**

As in Python, the default value for 2nd arg of `open` is `r`, you can simple do `open('newfile.txt')`

Answer (score 2):

You can't perform I/O operation on file_obj after closing it i.e.

```
file_obj.close()
```

So if you want to open the same file do:

```
if(file_obj.closed):
   file_obj = open(file_obj.name, file_obj.mode)

print (file.obj.read())
file_obj.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

As illustrated above when you closed the file you need to open your file so that you can read it

```
f = open('newfile.txt', 'r')
print f.read()
f.close()
```